# Writing Data Fails With CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION After Many Writeback Calls

Tags: c++, json, curl, https, libcurl

Essentially, I have a write callback that I set for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION. I also set my pointer for writing the data to in CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.

I run an infinite while loop for around 5 seconds, then CURLOPT fails to right data to the void* up pointer defined in CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, then after that one failure it starts working again. I got tons of successful writes sprinkled with failures. Is this a memory issue, and if so, is there a way to circumvent reaching this issue altogether?

```
// these locations will likely be different on your local.    
#include "../cygwin64/usr/include/curl/curl.h"
#include "../cygwin64/usr/include/json/json.h"

size_t write_callback(char *buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up) {
  size_t num_bytes = size*nmemb;
  std::string* data = (std::string*) up;
  for(int i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++) {
    data->push_back(buf[i]);
  }
  return num_bytes;
}


CURL* init_curl(struct curl_slist *headers, std::string* chunk) {
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_callback);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) chunk);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
  return curl;
 }

bool curl_get(struct curl_slist *headers, const std::string& url,
  Json::Value* json_res) {

  // this is where my data should be written to
  std::string data;
  CURL* curl = init_curl(headers, &data);
  CURLcode res;
  bool success = true;
  if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
      std::cout << "Could not perform get for " << url << std::endl;
      std::cout << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
      success = false;
    } else {
      Json::Value json_data;
      Json::CharReaderBuilder json_reader;
      std::istringstream stream_data(data);
      std::string errs;
      if(Json::parseFromStream(json_reader, stream_data, &json_data, &errs)) {
        std::cout << "successfully parsed JSON data for: " << url << std::endl;
        *json_res = json_data;
      } else {
        std::cout << "failed to parse JSON data for: " << url << std::endl;
        std::cout << errs << std::endl;
        std::cout << json_data << std::endl;
        std::cout << "finished failing" << std::endl;
        success = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    success = false;
  }
  curl_slist_free_all(headers);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  return success;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    while (true) {


          Json::Value response;
          if (curl_get(headers, "https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/?symbols=AMZN", &response)) {
               std::cout << response << std::endl;
          } else {

               // reaches here sometimes because response (my data) is null
               std::cout << "failed to get last trade price" << std::endl;
          }
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Expect no failures, but I get intermittent failures to right the data to my WRITEDATA chunk.

Comment: And there are no other "errors" or problems, nothing is output from your program  when the data is empty? Have you checked the log on the *server* side, and what happens there when you get empty responses?

Comment: instead of that loop, you can use std::string::append, check this: ```size_t curl_write_hook(const void * read_ptr, const size_t size,
  const size_t count, void *s_ptr)
{
 (*(string*) s_ptr).append((const char*) read_ptr, size * count);
 return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I can double check the logs, but when I set verbose, there don’t seem to be any failures. All that I notice is nothing gets populated in my data pointer once in awhile. I’ll take another look though, was pretty tired when writing this code. Was just worried if this was somehow something memory related where I had reached some write limit and libcurl would fail if beyond a certain write limit. Doesn’t really explain why it works immediately in the following iteration though after a failure.